# Codeigniter exception during transaction, what happens?

Tags: codeigniter, exception, transactions

In CodeIgniter what happens during a transaction if an exception is thrown?

```
$this->db->trans_start();
$this->db->query('some query');
throw new Exception('error');
$this->db->query('some query');
$this->db->trans_complete();
```

I'm assuming nothing gets committed until `trans_complete()`, but I couldn't find any concrete evidence in the documentation.

Answer (score 0):

For future reference an Exception thrown between queries before calling `trans_complete()` will result in *no* queries getting committed as expected.

Confirmed with tests.